# How to achieve the effect of blurred moving clock hands in photoshop?

Tags: post-processing, photoshop, photo-editing, effect

I got a newsletter which includes this picture

[image]

and I was wondering how the effect on the clock is achieved in photoshop.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Spin Blur**

In Photoshop (Photoshop CC 2014) it can be found in:

```
Filter > Blur Gallery > Spin Blur
```

You can find more info in [Adobe Photoshop documentation](http://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/blur-gallery.html#Spin_blur).

Comment: on old versions of PS it is named Radial blur

Comment: Radial Blur exists in newer versions too. Spin Blur is just Radial Blur set to spin and applied with a control widget.

Answer (score 9):

It's just the Radial Blur filter. However, if the idea is to replicate a slow shutter speed blurring the motion of the hands, it's poorly executed, because the entire clock face is blurred. Only the hands move, so only the hands should be blurred.

Comment: Radial blur goes outwards from a central point. This is spin blur, as the blur is going around the central point (the clock hands)

Comment: Radial blur has two modes, Zoom and Spin. The spin mode is exactly the same as Spin Blur, it just doesn't have the adjustment handles.

Comment: ah ok, I hadn't realised that, I was using 'radial' with its more mathematical meaning obviously :)